# Exception of type 'Stylelabs.M.Common.Web.Api.Validation.HttpResponseException' was thrown

Tags: content-hub

I am getting an exception while accessing a "Content Collection" created by the current user itself in Sitecore Content Hub 4.0.

> Exception of type
> 'Stylelabs.M.Common.Web.Api.Validation.HttpResponseException' was
> thrown.

[image]

Comment: Have you added any custom components to the content collection page?

Comment: No. Its a default simple page without any custom components. @RichardSeal